# clojure REPL - connect from another process

Tags: java, clojure

how to connect to existing clojure REPL from ClojureScript or from Java?

the question from title. Is there a helper class/library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

check out the network repl [nrepl](https://github.com/clojure/tools.nrepl)

it lets you connect to your repl over a network from any code you want

Comment: ok, thanks. And what about clojurescript? Should I implement socket protocol connection by hand?

Comment: I would expect someone to have built this,please follow up if you find a good one

Answer (score 5):

You are probably using Leiningen, so:

```
lein repl :connect 51000
```

(where the last number is the existing port number from the `.nrepl-port` file)